# Drawing parametric curve failure with tkz-fct

Tags: tkz-fct

I'm using TeXLive, compile with XeTeX. Trying to draw some curves. These are done well with tkz-fct, but when I need an inverted function, I experienced some strangenesses.

1; For \tkzFctPar the id command parameter makes no sense. The filename is main.tkzparfct.gnuplot, for any sake. I have to solve it manually - tiring.

2; The domain, when no given, returns a very strange curve. When given, the curve ends in a wrong point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4500\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2.5,xmax=2,ymin=-2.5,ymax=2,]
        \tkzAxeXY
        \tkzFct[id=circleArmyAbove,domain=-2:2]{sqrt(4-x**2)}
        \draw plot [smooth] file {main.circleArmyAbove.table};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.4500\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2.5,xmax=2,ymin=-2.5,ymax=2,]
        \tkzAxeXY
        \tkzFct[id=circleArmyBelow,domain=-2:2]{-sqrt(4-x**2)}
        \draw plot [smooth] file {main.circleArmyBelow.table};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.4500\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2.5,xmax=2,ymin=-2.5,ymax=2,]
        \tkzAxeXY
        \tkzFctPar[id=circleArmyRight]{sqrt(4-t**2)}{t}
        \draw plot [smooth] file {main.circleArmyRight.table};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.4500\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-2.5,xmax=2,ymin=-2.5,ymax=2,]
        \tkzAxeXY
        \tkzFctPar[id=circleArmyLeft]{-sqrt(4-t**2)}{t}
        \draw plot [smooth] file {main.circleArmyLeft.table};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Four curves}\label{fig:2.7}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The first two figures are okay, the second two are the problematic ones.

Reading the manual makes complication because it is written in french, what I don't understand.

Comment: ``Package pgf Warning: Plot data file `benko.circleArmyAbove.table' not found.``

Comment: @egreg Probably because you called your main file `benko.tex`. The OP probably called theirs main.tex`, but it makes IMHO more sense to use `\draw plot [smooth] file {\jobname.circleArmyRight.table};` and so on but I do not think that is the intended usage either.

Comment: If you replace all the `\draw plot ...` commands by `\draw plot [smooth] file {\jobname.tkzparfct.table};` you produce the plots. I doubt this is the intended usage, though. You do not have to add any `\draw plot ...` to get the curves. That is, I do not understand the question.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: I need TWO gnuplot file, but it produses ONE. The idea that the id=<tablename> parameter creates main.<jobname>.gnuplot file, as it does for the \tkzFct command, but it doesn't do.

Comment: Please explain your question. Why do you want two `gnuplot` files. Please make an effort of explaining what you want to achieve in detail. At the moment there are only some complaints but no information (that I can understand) whatsoever what you want to achieve, and how you try to achieve it, and why you chose the path. There is also no information (that I can understand) on the desired outcome.

Comment: How I tried is written. I need these four curve for an example of a differential equations solution.